# How to properly connect native node module (node-gyp) in to electron vue renderer process?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, vite, node-gyp

I have built my native node module using `electron-rebuild -v 24.4.0` and moved in to my electron@24.4.0 empty project generated by vite. I'm able to import and call functions from this native node module in main process without any error, but if i'm trying to do the same in renderer process I'm getting folowing error

[image]

Here is my `electron.vite.config.ts`

```
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { defineConfig, externalizeDepsPlugin } from 'electron-vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import native from "rollup-plugin-native";

export default defineConfig({
  main: {
    plugins: [externalizeDepsPlugin()]
  },
  preload: {
    plugins: [externalizeDepsPlugin()]
  },
  renderer: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@renderer': resolve('src/renderer/src')
      }
    },
    plugins: [
      vue(),
      native(),
    ]
  }
});
```

I use `rollup-plugin-native` to be able work with `.node` files. I use node.js `18.16.0` and electron `24.4.0`.
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 108 - is my local.
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 114 - is version which used to build native node module.
So where can be the problem? I'm able to use native module in main process but not in renderer process. How can I fix that?